# How to fit a content in a column of LaTeX table?

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

I am trying to create a table in LaTeX. However content of my column is exceeding the width and intruding in the other column. Please help me to solve this problem.
Code is pasted below.Screenshot of output is attached herewith

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf, authordraft]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Quality metrics with reference image-MS and HH SAR}                                    
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.6 cm} p{1.3 cm} p{1.5 cm} p{1.5 cm} p{1.5 cm} p{1.5 cm}p{1.5 cm}}
\toprule
Sl. No. & Metric & Band  &PCA &DWT &IHS-DWT &PCA-DWT \\
\midrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{SCC (SAR \& Fused Image)} & Green  &0.635  &0.550 &0.590 &0.525  \\
 & & Red &0.453 &0.468 &0.514 &0.343  \\                
 & & NIR &0.783 &0.501 &0.368 &0.486 \\                                 
 & & SWIR &0.642    &0.504 &0.432 &0.425 \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{2} & \multirow{4}{*}{SCC  (Original MS \& Fused Image)} & Green  &0.214  &0.595 &0.343 &0.540  \\
 & & Red &0.701 &0.649 &0.554 &0.830  \\                
 & & NIR &0.321 &0.623 &0.846 &0.687 \\                                 
 & & SWIR &0.463    &0.615 &0.738 &0.731 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `tabularx` package and let latex determine the best widths for your columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're complicating easy things by manually hardcoding column widths. Just use natural column widths, `lllcccc`, unless you have really long text in some columns.

```
\documentclass[sigconf, authordraft]{acmart}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Quality metrics with reference image-MS and HH SAR}                                    
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllcccc@{}}
\toprule
Sl. No.            & Metric                                             & Band  & PCA   & DWT   & IHS-DWT & PCA-DWT \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{SCC (SAR \& Fused Image)}          & Green & 0.635 & 0.550 & 0.590   & 0.525   \\
                   &                                                    & Red   & 0.453 & 0.468 & 0.514   & 0.343   \\
                   &                                                    & NIR   & 0.783 & 0.501 & 0.368   & 0.486   \\
                   &                                                    & SWIR  & 0.642 & 0.504 & 0.432   & 0.425   \\
\bottomrule
\multirow{4}{*}{2} & \multirow{4}{*}{SCC (Original MS \& Fused Image)}  & Green & 0.214 & 0.595 & 0.343   & 0.540   \\
                   &                                                    & Red   & 0.701 & 0.649 & 0.554   & 0.830   \\
                   &                                                    & NIR   & 0.321 & 0.623 & 0.846   & 0.687   \\
                   &                                                    & SWIR  & 0.463 & 0.615 & 0.738   & 0.731   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make the second column a little bit wider (`p{1.7 cm}` instead of `p{1.3 cm}`) and use `\shortstack` to break the lines:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, authordraft]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Quality metrics with reference image-MS and HH SAR}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.6 cm} p{1.7 cm} p{1.5 cm} p{1.5 cm} p{1.5 cm} p{1.5 cm}p{1.5 cm}}
\toprule
Sl. No. & Metric & Band  &PCA &DWT &IHS-DWT &PCA-DWT \\
\midrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{\shortstack{SCC \\ (SAR \\ \& Fused Image)}} & Green  &0.635  &0.550 &0.590 &0.525  \\
 & & Red &0.453 &0.468 &0.514 &0.343  \\
 & & NIR &0.783 &0.501 &0.368 &0.486 \\
 & & SWIR &0.642    &0.504 &0.432 &0.425 \\
  \bottomrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{2} & \multirow{4}{*}{\shortstack{SCC \\ (Original MS \\ \& Fused Image)}} & Green  &0.214  &0.595 &0.343 &0.540  \\
 & & Red &0.701 &0.649 &0.554 &0.830  \\
 & & NIR &0.321 &0.623 &0.846 &0.687 \\
 & & SWIR &0.463    &0.615 &0.738 &0.731 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ DG, My string is quite longer than this. Is it possible to continue the text in second column to new line.....

Comment: @sckulkarni Please edit your question so that it represents your actual problem

Comment: I have edited my question. Edited your answer by mistake.